# Setting an object property with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have two custom UserControl in my project code: TableControl and DeckControl. In the code of the latter I would be able to access the former when it's needed. So in my DeckControl I implemented the following property:

```
private TableControl m_Table;

public TableControl Table
{
    get { return m_Table; }
    set { m_Table = value; }
}
```

The problem is that I'm not able to set the property from XAML code:

```
<Canvas Core:Name="Layout" Loaded="OnLayoutLoaded">
    <Namespace:TableControl Core:Name="Table" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=Layout, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=Layout, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    <Namespace:DeckControl Core:Name="Deck" Canvas.Left="50">
</Canvas>
```

I tried using Reference but compiler says that the method or opera

```
<Namespace:DeckControl Core:Name="Deck" Canvas.Left="50" Table="{Core:Reference Name=Table}">
```

I tried this but it isn't working either:

```
<Namespace:DeckControl Core:Name="Deck" Canvas.Left="50" Table="{Core:Static Table}">
```

I also tried using Binding:

```
<Namespace:DeckControl Core:Name="Deck" Canvas.Left="50" Table="{Binding ElementName=Table}">
```

Ok so... it's my first approach to XAML and I'm still working on it... but I really can't get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind to a property in youe Model(window/Usercontrol) codebehind you have to set the `DataContext` in your `Xaml`.
There are may ways to do this but the simpliest is just naming your window or usercontrol and binding using `ElementName`.

Example for a Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="233" Width="143" Name="UI">

    <Canvas DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}" > <!-- Set dataContext to Window -->
        <Namespace:DeckControl Canvas.Left="50" Table="{Binding ElementName=Table}">
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

And if you want the `Xaml` to update when Table changes your code behind should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, this will inform the `Xaml` that the property has changed.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private TableControl m_Table;

    public TableControl Table
    {
       get { return m_Table; }
       set { m_Table = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Table"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

If your Table property is not a DependancyProperty you will have to chage this so you can bind.

Example:

```
public class DeckControl : UserControl
 {
     .......



     // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Table.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
     public static readonly DependencyProperty TableProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Table", typeof(TableControl), typeof(DeckControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

     public TableControl Table
     {
         get { return (TableControl)GetValue(TableProperty); }
         set { SetValue(TableProperty, value); }
     }
 }
```

Also any property that is being binded outside the scope of the UserControl has to be a DependancyProperty.

Example:

```
public partial class DeckControl : UserControl
{
    public DeckControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int myVar;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }
}
```

This will bind inside the usercontrol when it is a simple property as it is inscope.

```
<UserControl .....
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Name="UI">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
</UserControl>
```

This will not bind as its out of scope of the UserControl, MyProperty will have to be a DependancyProperty to bind here

```
<Window ....
        Title="MainWindow" Height="233" Width="143" Name="UI">

    <Grid>
        <local:DeckControl MyProperty="{Binding Width}"  /> // Will not bind
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: I tried but I'm getting this error: "A Binding cannot be set on the Table property of type DeckControl. A Binding can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject"

Comment: Is `DeckControl` your control or a 3rd party control, It sounds like `Table` is not a `DependancyProperty` so you wont be able to bind using Xaml, If it is your control you can change the `DeckControls` Table property into a `DependancyProperty` and this will allow binding.

Comment: Both DeckControl and TableControl inherits UserControl. They are custom user controls.

Comment: Then setting `Table` in `DeckControl` as a `DependancyProperty` will allow you to bind in your `xaml`, I added an example of a `DependanceyProperty` to my answer.

Comment: In my DeckControl I have a property like this: public Int32 MaximumSpace { get { return m_MaximumSpace; } set { m_MaximumSpace = value; } }... why I can set that one in XAML without need of registering a DependancyProperty like so?

Comment: Where are you binding this `int` property, within the usercontrol or from the control hosting the usercontrol, If you are binding within the scope of the usercontrol a DependancyProperty is not needed, but if you are binding a property from your main window to your DeckControls `int` property it will have to be a dependancyproperty. added info to answer